# partclone via clonezilla - where are the bad blocks logged?

Tags: backup, logging, clonezilla, bad-blocks

I've just backed up a partition using clonezilla, which in turn employed partclone. During the backup, several blocks were bad and were skipped (it was in rescue mode). Is there a log of these?

Answer (score 1):

There's a log in `/var/log/partclone.log`, which lists the bad sectors:

```
WARNING: Can't read sector at 189696286720, lost data.
WARNING: Can't read sector at 189696287232, lost data.
WARNING: Can't read sector at 189696287744, lost data.
WARNING: Can't read sector at 189696288256, lost data.
```

but it seems the correlation with actual filenames is not logged (it's also not displayed during the partition cloning).

Comment: I suspect that correlating bad sector numbers with actual file data is involved enough to deserve its own, separate question.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator: Ok, fair enough.